# How to use CORS with azure traffic manager

Tags: azure, cors, azure-traffic-manager

I am using azure traffic manager for load balancing of my virtual machines. But it is giving CORS blocked error when calling from ajax.

I have CORS enabled for my machines url.

can any one provide me some solutions.

Comment: Can you provide the configuration for how you have enabled CORS on your VMS?

Comment: I used following configurations with my ASP.net Web Api service - In webApiconfig -    config.EnableCors(); and in my api controller -   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*",SupportsCredentials = true)] ;

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are calling the traffic manager load balanced endpoint from a page that is on a different domain, is that right? Like your HTML page is on domain.com, and ajax in your page is calling domain.trafficmanager.com - is that why your getting CORS exceptions? If so can you just change the CNAME for your domain.com to point to domain.trafficmanager.com so your whole website is served from the same domain? Of course this implies your application server for both HTML / Javascript, etc. are all being served by the same process (not sure if that's the case here).